# Plug-in RMI for Eclipse

Tags: rmi

can anyone help me to send RMI plug-in with Eclips Indigo.. I have tried a lot to use RMI with Eclips, but I could not, please help me to know about it, because I need it a lot...

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You have this http://www.genady.net/rmi/index.html RMI plugin for eclipse. There is instructions to install it and to use it, just read the documention.

Comment: do not use this plugin it's pure scam , all they want is money, expires after 4 months